Veeam Backup Agent error during blksnap compile on PROXMOX 8 / Debian12
On our two PROXMOX servers version 8.2.2 do we have a compile problem with veeam blksnap.
dkms install -m blksnap -v 6.1.0.1498 Sign command: /lib/modules/6.8.4-2-pve/build/scripts/sign-file Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module: Cleaning build area... make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.4-2-pve -j16 -C /lib/modules/6.8.4-2-pve/build M=/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build modules...(bad exit status: 2) Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.4-2-pve (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/make.log for more information.

I tried to understand the log /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/make.log, but I couldn't find a solution so far.
 DKMS make.log for blksnap-6.1.0.1498 for kernel 6.8.4-2-pve (x86_64)
Fri Apr 26 02:49:00 PM CEST 2024
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.4-2-pve'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/bdevfilter.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/log.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/big_buffer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/cbt_map.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/chunk.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/ctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_buffer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/event_queue.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapimage.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapshot.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/memory_checker.o
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/log.c:246:5: warning: no previous prototype for ‘log_processor’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
  246 | int log_processor(void *data)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_io.c:45:6: warning: no previous prototype for ‘diff_io_endio’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
   45 | void diff_io_endio(struct bio *bio)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c: In function ‘diff_area_free’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c:123:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_put’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  123 |                 blkdev_put(diff_area->orig_bdev, NULL);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.c: In function ‘diff_storage_free’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.c:123:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_put’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  123 |                 blkdev_put(storage_bdev->bdev, NULL);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/ctrl.c:444:5: warning: no previous prototype for ‘ioctl_mod’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
  444 | int ioctl_mod(unsigned long arg)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/ctrl.c:454:5: warning: no previous prototype for ‘ioctl_setlog’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
  454 | int ioctl_setlog(unsigned long arg)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:23:9: note: ‘#pragma message: Standalone bdevfilter’
   23 | #pragma message("Standalone bdevfilter")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:29:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The void submit_bio_noacct(struct bio *) function was found.’
   29 | #pragma message("The void submit_bio_noacct(struct bio *) function was found.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:35:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The struct bio have pointer to struct block_device.’
   35 | #pragma message("The struct bio have pointer to struct block_device.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:41:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The bdev_nr_sectors() function was found.’
   41 | #pragma message("The bdev_nr_sectors() function was found.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:44:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The blk_mq_alloc_disk() function was found.’
   44 | #pragma message("The blk_mq_alloc_disk() function was found.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:50:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The function add_disk() has a return code.’
   50 | #pragma message("The function add_disk() has a return code.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/main.c:56:9: note: ‘#pragma message: The function bio_alloc_bioset() has a parameter bdev.’
   56 | #pragma message("The function bio_alloc_bioset() has a parameter bdev.")
      |         ^~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c: In function ‘diff_area_new’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c:296:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_get_by_dev’; did you mean ‘blkdev_get_no_open’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  296 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE, NULL, NULL);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                blkdev_get_no_open
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c:296:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  296 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.c: In function ‘diff_storage_add_storage_bdev’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.c:162:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_get_by_dev’; did you mean ‘blkdev_get_no_open’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  162 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE, NULL, NULL);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                blkdev_get_no_open
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.c:162:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  162 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.c:395:15: warning: no previous prototype for ‘diff_area_chunk_take’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
  395 | struct chunk *diff_area_chunk_take(struct diff_area *diff_area,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapshot.c: In function ‘snapshot_release_trackers’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapshot.c:58:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeze_bdev’; did you mean ‘freeze_super’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   58 |                 if (freeze_bdev(tracker->diff_area->orig_bdev))
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     freeze_super
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘tracker_filter_attach’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:242:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeze_bdev’; did you mean ‘freeze_super’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  242 |         if (freeze_bdev(bdev))
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |             freeze_super
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapshot.c:79:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘thaw_bdev’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   79 |                 if (thaw_bdev(tracker->diff_area->orig_bdev))
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:259:21: error: implicit declaration of function ‘thaw_bdev’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  259 |                 if (thaw_bdev(bdev))
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘tracker_create_or_get’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:476:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_get_by_dev’; did you mean ‘blkdev_get_no_open’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  476 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                blkdev_get_no_open
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:476:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  476 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapimage.c: In function ‘snapimage_create’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapimage.c:292:47: error: ‘BLK_DEF_MAX_SECTORS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘BLK_SAFE_MAX_SECTORS’?
  292 |         blk_queue_max_hw_sectors(disk->queue, BLK_DEF_MAX_SECTORS);
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               BLK_SAFE_MAX_SECTORS
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapimage.c:292:47: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:531:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘blkdev_put’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  531 |         blkdev_put(bdev, NULL);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘tracker_remove’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:548:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  548 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘tracker_read_cbt_bitmap’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:626:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  626 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘collect_cbt_info’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:678:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  678 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c: In function ‘tracker_mark_dirty_blocks’:
/var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.c:765:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct block_device *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  765 |         bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(dev_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
      |              ^
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapimage.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_storage.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/diff_area.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/snapshot.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build/tracker.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.4-2-pve/Makefile:1926: /var/lib/dkms/blksnap/6.1.0.1498/build] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.4-2-pve'

It might be some one better in this as me? Thanks for any help!

When blksnap 6.1.0 was released the 6.8 kernel was not there, its support was added later for 6.1.2
Try to build it from blksnap repository: https://github.com/veeam/blksnap
If you'll have issue try to look https://github.com/veeam/blksnap/issues/88
